# Zend_Mail - Fetch IMAP Attachements from GMAIL

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap

I habe some trouble with Zend Framework and fetching Attachements from GMAIL. Authentication is handeld by oAuth.

It is no problem to fetch the Mailtext, but i cant fetch the attachement, or better i have no idea how to do it (;

```
        if ($message->isMultiPart()) {

            $iParts = $message->countParts();

            for ($i = 1; $i < $iParts; $i++) {
                $part = $message->getPart($i);

                // ATTACHEMENT?
                if () {
                    // DO MAIL DOWNLOAD
                }

                // MAIL TEXT
                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
                    $encoding = $part->getHeader('content-transfer-encoding');
                    $contentType = $part->getHeader('content-type');
                    $content = $part->getContent();
                    break;
                } 
            }
```

Header from my mail (removed some details):

> ```
> [delivered-to] => xxxx@gmail.com
> [received] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 
>         [1] => 
>         [2] => 
>         [3] => 
>     )
> [return-path] => 
> [received-spf] => 
> [authentication-results] => 
> [dkim-signature] =>
> [mime-version] => 1.0
> [from] => 
> [date] => Thu, 30 Aug 2012 17:16:37 +0200
> [message-id] => 
> [subject] => ANHANG
> [to] => 
> [content-type] => multipart/mixed; boundary=f46d043bd88a9f5d9404c87d2ad5
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it but, if it works, you owe me a beer... Anyways, Try this: Logically it should work...

```
if ($message->isMultiPart()) {
     $part = $message->getPart(2);
}

       // Remember mails with attachment are MULTI-part? (:
       $filename = $part->getHeader('content-description');
       $attachment = base64_decode($part->getContent()); //we decode because mails are encoded with base 64

       // File operations
       $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
       fwrite($fh, $attachment);
       fclose($fh);
```

If u get error, post it here

or if it works, gimme a tick ;)

Comment: thanks but how to identify that there is an attachement? (have a look at my posted header example). Or is part 2 everytime an attachement?

Comment: I edited my answer :P yea, it seems you have an attachment because : [content-type] => multipart/mixed; boundary=f46d043bd88a9f5d9404c87d2ad5

Comment: so, what happens? you tried my script? expect a typo since I just got on typing without testing...

Comment: Thanks works, it is a bit strange because there is no correct header for the "text" part of the message (part 1)

Comment: woah! *pats his back* yes, because in multi-part, mail considers first part as text - by default. Glad it worked out! :)